# MTKView compositing one UIImage at a time

Tags: swift, buffer, metal, render-to-texture, metalkit

I have an array of `UIImages` that I want to composite via an `MTKView` using a variety of specific comp modes (source-over, erase, etc). With the approach I describe below, I find that the biggest overhead seems to be in converting each `UIImage` into an `MTLTexture` that I can use to populate an `MTKView's` `currentDrawable` buffer.

The drawing loop looks like this:

```
for strokeDataCurrent in strokeDataArray {

    let strokeImage = UIImage(data: strokeDataCurrent.image)  // brushstroke   
    let strokeBbox = strokeDataCurrent.bbox  // brush bounding box          
    let strokeType = strokeDataCurrent.strokeType // used to define comp mode

    // convert strokeImage to a MTLTexture and composite
    drawStrokeImage(paintingViewMetal: self.canvasMetalViewPainting, strokeImage: strokeImage!, strokeBbox: strokeBbox, strokeType: strokeType)

} // end of for strokeDataCurrent in strokeDataArray
```

Inside of drawStrokeImage, I convert each stroke to an `MTLTexture` like this:

```
guard let stampTexture = device!.makeTexture(descriptor: texDescriptor) else { return }
let destCGImage = strokeImage.cgImage!
let dstData: CFData = (destCGImage!.dataProvider!.data)!
let pixelData = CFDataGetBytePtr(dstData) 
let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, Int(width), Int(height))
stampTexture.replace(region: region, mipmapLevel: 0, withBytes: pixelData!, bytesPerRow: Int(rowBytes))
```

with all this in place, I define a vertex buffer, set a `commandEncoder`:

```
defineCommandEncoder(renderCommandEncoder: renderCommandEncoder, vertexArrayStamps: vertexArrayStamps, metalTexture: stampTexture)
```

and call `setNeedsDisplay()` to render.  This is happening for each stroke in the above for loop.

While I get ok performance in this approach, I'm wondering if I can squeeze more performance somewhere along the way?  Like I said, I think the current bottleneck is in going from `CGImage -> MTLTexture`.

Note that I am rendering to a defined `MTLTexture` metalDrawableTextureComposite which I am blitting to the `currentDrawable` for each stroke:

```
copyTexture(buffer: commandBuffer!, from: metalDrawableTextureComposite, to: self.currentDrawable!.texture)
```

Hopefully this is enough detail to provide context for my question.  Also, if anyone has ideas for other (GPU/Metal-based hopefully) faster compositing approaches that would be awesome. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: How dynamic are your brushstroke images? I would expect them to be fairly static (i.e. not changing for every stroke or anywhere near that). So, you should convert them to textures once, not for every draw!

Comment: Indeed, the brushstrokes are completely static.  They're stored as UIImage (pngData) for compression efficiency. If I understand your comment, you’re saying why not create an array of Mtltexture from array of UIImage once, and then use that during my draw loop? If so, that sounds attractive, but is that workable memory-wise? I’m not quite clear where/how Mtltextures are stored. I was under the impression that I have limited texture memory to work with, but perhaps the conversion I'm doing is actually just creating pointers to the pngData for MTKView usage.  Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: You might use a texture atlas instead of individual textures per brushstroke, but other than that it's the right approach. How many brushstroke images are we talking about? I wouldn't think that all of them put together would rival some of the individual textures used in a typical 3D game, for example. If necessary, you can manage a cache of limited size. If you need a texture that isn't loaded, you load it and add it to the cache. If that exceeds the size limit you establish, then drop some other, least-recently-used texture from the cache.

Comment: Thanks Ken.  The problem is that the brushstrokes in question can number in the hundreds or potentially thousands, as this is a painting app in which I intend to support full history undo/redo.  As for the cache idea, is there a maximum number I should aim toward?

Comment: To be clear, although the total array of UIImages may number in the thousands, I only send 250 of these to be redrawn by MTKView at any given time.  That said, which 250 set of images get sent depends on where in history the user chooses to playback from. This is why I've gone with the approach of rebuilding the MTLTextures every time I want to redraw...I had a sense that this is not the smartest way to go, but I'm not seeing another viable alternative.

Comment: What does undo/redo have to do with it if the brushstrokes are static? Whether or how often a brushstroke is used in a document's history shouldn't matter. It still should just exist once (at most) in the app's memory. I should also have asked how big the brushstroke images are. Suppose they're 32x32 pixels. Then a 1024x1024 texture atlas can contain 1024 brushstroke images, and that's not a particularly large texture atlas. And games get away with many such textures.

Comment: As far as how large the cache should be, use the `recommendedMaxWorkingSetSize` and `currentAllocatedSize` properties of the Metal device to guide you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194999/discussion-between-plutovman-and-ken-thomases).

Comment: You will run out of memory with that many images in a row if you decode them to memory. It would be harder to get right, but if you want a performance improvement then the only way to get it would be to encode the brush strokes as H264 video and then decode frame by frame and apply your effects to each frame as they are decoded.